# selected option change text value

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I don't know how to ask. But I need help. I have selected option like this

```
<select id="cat_req" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value ="A">Andreas - Accounting</option>
    <option value ="B">Britina - Finance</option>
    <option value ="C">Chirstina - Purchasing</option>
    <option value ="D">Daniel - Merchandising</option>
</select>
```

When I select option A, I need text selected show Andreas not Andreas - Accounting, how do I do that on php???
Anyway this is just simple, in real code I used MySQL and framework ( not CI)

Comment: 1) Add a `name` attribute in your `<select>` element. 2) Catch the selected option using `$_POST` or `$_GET` superglobal(based on your form's `method` attribute) 3) Finally, use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string and display appropriate string component.

Comment: probarly my question kinda miss here. I mean i need view value on selected "cat_req", when i pick value "A", in "cat_req" text alue change to Andreas not Andreas - Accounting.

Comment: Are you looking for this kind of behavior, [https://jsfiddle.net/ntk8yqq7/](https://jsfiddle.net/ntk8yqq7/)? Your question and the subsequent comment is not very clear.